# Syntax for Registering Generic Interface and Concrete Class with Simple Injector PerWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, simple-injector

I am having trouble getting the correct syntax for registering a generic interface and its concrete implementation with Simple Injector on a PerWebRequest basis.

This is the line registering with Simple Injector's container in `Global.asax` that causes the error:

```
 container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUnitOfWork<>, UnitOfWork<>>();
```

For completeness, these are the interface and concrete class definitions:

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork<TContext>
    where TContext : IContext {

     public UnitOfWork(TContext context) {

     }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork<TContext> where TContext : IContext
{
    TContext Context { get; }
}
```

I am getting the error : `Type Argument is Missing` from IntelliSense in Visual Studio (the first type parameter on `container.RegisterPerWebRequest` : `IUnitOfWork<>` is underlined in red)

What should the correct syntax be?

Comment: Did you check the documentation: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=open%20generics#registration-of-open-generic-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting is a C# compiler error; the C# compiler (and the CLR) don't accept open-generics in method arguments.

The `RegisterPerWebRequest` has been obsoleted in v3 (it's still there for backwards compatibility). The best way is to do this:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

container.Register(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>), typeof(UnitOfWork<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```